# Trying to throw an exception when a radio button hasnt been selected

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi there I'm just developing a very small based windows app trying to get into the swing of things again. The problem that I'am having is that I'm trying to throw an exception when a radio button hasn't been checked so that a message box appears to tell the user to select a radio button. However I cant remember what exception to throw or how to achieve it. I have provided a small code snippet for yous to see on how I go about doing this. I was going to put an else statement following the if statements but cant remember what to throw. The app is a small very basic calculator.

```
 if ((bool)Addition.IsChecked.HasValue && Addition.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                calcualteAdditionSum(val1, val2);
            }

            if ((bool)Subtract.IsChecked.HasValue && Subtract.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                calculateSubtractSun(val1, val2);
            }

            if ((bool)Remainder.IsChecked.HasValue && Remainder.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                calculateRemainderSun(val1, val2);
            }

            if ((bool)Multiply.IsChecked.HasValue && Multiply.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                calculateMultiplySum(val1, val2);
            }

            if ((bool)Division.IsChecked.HasValue && Division.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                calculateDivisionSum(val1, val2);
            }


        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please ensure you have selected a checkBox\nand provided a number in the textboxes");
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to throw an exception or catch anything. Just create a `bool` variable and initialize it to `false` at the beginning of the procedure. This variable will store information if any button is selected. Change its value to `true` inside every `if` block and check its state at the end. If it's still `false`, show a message.

**EDIT**

Basically, you should throw exceptions when something bad happens. I wouldn't classify not selecting any radio button as something bad.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th `if` statements to be `else if` statements instead (unless I'm missing something - if they're radio buttons, then it doesn't seem that it should be possible to have more than one of those conditions at a time) and then I would add an `else` statement on the end that displays a message box explaining to the user to chose one of radio buttons. No exceptions needed.